# Read image path from Mysql

Tags: java, imageview, javafx-2

I need to load multiple images from database. In order to retrieve image path i use following codes but i cannot display image on scene.

```
c[i] = m_ResultSet.getString(3);// take image path from db

for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

    try {
        final Image image = images[j] = new Image(c[j]);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
    final ImageView pic = pics[j] = new ImageView(images[j]);
    pic.setEffect(shadow);
    pic.setEffect(reflection);

    vb.getChildren().add(pics[j]);

}
```

in this way i cannot see any image on scene. Any suggestion for read image from db and show on scene?

I solve the problem

```
                for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++) {
        files =c [j];
        File f4 = new File(files);
        try{
        final Image image = images[j] =
            new Image(f4.toURI().toString(), 256, 256, false, false);

        }
        catch(NullPointerException e ){
  }
        final ImageView pic = pics[j] =
            new ImageView(images[j]);
        pic.setEffect(shadow);
        pic.setEffect(reflection);

        vb.getChildren().add(pics[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the Classloader cannot find the images for the given URLs. Since you didn't provide a "Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)", the only suggestion I can do for you now is to partially quote the API of `javafx.scene.image.Image`:

```
// Example code for loading images.

import javafx.scene.image.Image;

// load an image in background, displaying a placeholder while it's loading
// (assuming there's an ImageView node somewhere displaying this image)
// The image is located in default package of the classpath
Image image1 = new Image("/flower.png", true);

// load an image and resize it to 100x150 without preserving its original
// aspect ratio
// The image is located in my.res package of the classpath
Image image2 = new Image("my/res/flower.png", 100, 150, false, false);

// load an image and resize it to width of 100 while preserving its
// original aspect ratio, using faster filtering method
// The image is downloaded from the supplied URL through http protocol
Image image3 = new Image("http://sample.com/res/flower.png", 100, 0, false, false);

// load an image and resize it only in one dimension, to the height of 100 and
// the original width, without preserving original aspect ratio
// The image is located in the current working directory
Image image4 = new Image("file:flower.png", 0, 100, false, false);
```

Compare the URLs of those examples with yours in DB, and confirm the existence of the images.

**EDIT:**
If you are reading images from localhost, try

```
final Image image = images[j] = new Image("file:///" + c[j]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer:)
My images paths are correct, I'am taking my image paths to array but ı cannot use string array to read image paths from.

final Image image = images[j] = new Image(c[j]);

Comment: For testing purposes, try to load a sample image on your desktop, on other server machine for example, then load the images from your DB URLs by using Strings directly (skip reading from DB).

Comment: I solve the problem 
<               for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++) {
            files =c [j];
            File f4 = new File(files);
            try{
            final Image image = images[j] =
                new Image(f4.toURI().toString(), 256, 256, false, false);
            
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e ){
      }
            final ImageView pic = pics[j] =
                new ImageView(images[j]);
            pic.setEffect(shadow);
            pic.setEffect(reflection);
            
            vb.getChildren().add(pics[j]);>